# How to call an angularJS function from javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I need to call an `angularJS` function from a `javascript` function. This is my `javascript` function:

```
function callAngularFunction(userid, serviceid, system) {

    angular.element(document.getElementById('myServiceId')).scope().test();

}
```

This is my controller code:

```
serviceApp.controller('myService', function ($scope,  $location, $window) {
    $scope.test = function () {
        console.log("hello from test");
    }
});
```

And this is how I included it in `html`:

```
<body ng-app="serviceApp" ng-controller="myService" id="myServiceId">
```

Whenever I call `callAngularFunction`, I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

Comment: looks like you do not have an HTML element with ID `myServiceId` in the `DOM`. To check it just execute `document.getElementById('myServiceId')` in your debugger console. It should print undefined if the element is not found.

Comment: @Andriy it can be possible cause the above code is deployed in server and I'm calling the function named ```callAngularFunction``` from my localhost project. But i'm new and have no idea how to proceed from here

Comment: try to inspect your available HTML code in debugger -> elements and try to find closest to your component element with unique `CSS selector `(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) (id, unique class or property) and then try to select it with `documnet.querySelector()` (instead of `document.getElementById()`)

Comment: Looking at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496372/how-to-call-functions-in-my-angularjs-projects-from-a-controller-deployed-in-ser), this appears to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your are trying to solve the previous problem on your own using a method that won't work. Thus obscuring the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are importing the scripts in the end of the body tag `</body>` maybe for that reason it is not available in your code the id `myServiceId`